# Swagger-ui of springdoc-openapi can't be opened if spring-mvc has default mapping url

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I found an issue that swagger-ui (http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html) of springdoc-openapi can't be opened if spring MVC application has a method with default mapping URL `@GetMapping("**")` (below).

```
@Controller
class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("**")
    fun notFound(): ModelAndView {
       return ModelAndView()
    }
}
```

Because the request to swagger-ui is also mapped to the following method.
If the method is removed, I can see the swagger page.

Is there any way to open the swagger page correctly while using the default mapping URL ?

I prepared sample codes to reproduce the issue.
https://github.com/policeman-kh/hello_spring_mvc

Versions:

```
spring-boot: 2.7.6
springdoc-openapi-ui: 1.6.13
```

I expect to open the swagger page correctly while using the default mapping URL.
Because using the default mapping URL is necessary to show a common error page.

Comment: I also got this error. Any solutions?